# JS connected to MySql set password security

Tags: javascript, mysql, security

I have this code here to connect to MySql inside a .JS file

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  database : 'abc',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'test',
});
```

Im going to post it on GITHUB. But how would I hide all these important details when I have posted the website? Im also very new to all this and have been following YouTube video clips to where I got to. Im just concerned about security of the code.

Comment: two choices: 1) remove the sensitive bits and post the file to GitHub. 2) add this file to your `.gitIgnore` file and provide instructions in your `README` for how to create the file.

Comment: *" Im just concerned about security of the code."* Your code seams to be serverside javascript meant to be run in `Node.js` It wil not run in a webbrowser so why are doubting security ?

Comment: Hi Raymond, like i said im new to this and trying to figure out how everything works.

Comment: As @RandyCasburn said, a good practice is for example to create a config.js file with your private variables (constants). Ignored with .gitignore. Then you can create a config.js.dist published to github with the name of your constants without the values.